# Sum across multiple columns in R with changing number of columns (2 to 3) using the column names pattern

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sapply

I have a dataframe with 10 columns.

I need to

- first sum the columns 1+2 and 3+4 together,
- then to sum up the columns 5+6+7 and 8+9+10;
- and save as a dataframe.

I have made it work (see below), but manually, using 2 `sapply` functions, then `t` and `rbind`, and thus I seek more elegant solution.

The **column names exhibit a clear pattern** across them.

The list for *the first 4 columns* looks like this:
`“on_b_, off_b_”` and repeat (thus I am summing up columns *1 & 2*, and then *3 & 4*)

The list for *the next 6 columns* looks like this:
`“on_b_, something else in between, off_b_”` and repeat (thus I am summing up *5 & 6 & 7* and then *8 & 9 & 10*)

**I need the function to restart once it sees the beginning of the list again**. **The beginning** one is the column with the name starting from `on_b_`:

> **on_b_**, *(something else entirely irrelevant in between, like CC_, or nothing at all)*, **off_b_**

**Here is the reproducible code chunk:**

```
df = structure(list(on_b_pos_1 = 64, off_b_4 = 25, 
                    on_b_6 = 28, off_b_8 = 157, 
                    on_b_3 = 42, CC_2 = 0,  off_b_4 = 125, 
                    on_b_5 = 51, CC_7 = 0, off_b_8 = 15), 
               row.names = 14L, class = "data.frame")
```

**This is what I have done before and it works:**

```
# adding together TWO columns
a <- data.frame(sapply(seq(1,4,by=2),function(i) rowSums(df[,i:(i+1)])))

# check whether the function i is getting the correct columns where it restarts
# seq(1,4,by=2) 

# adding together THREE columns
b <- data.frame(sapply(seq(5,ncol(df),by=3),function(i) rowSums(df[,i:(i+2)])))

# transpose
a <- t(a)
b <- t(b)

c <- cbind(a, b)
```

**The result should look like this:**

```
Column 1  Column 2  Column 3  Column 4
  89        185       167        66
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `map2` function from the `purrr` package, where you look for the column index that starts with "on" or "off" by `grep`.

If you have more than 1 row in your `df`, wrap my code with `sapply` or `map` to iterate over the rows.

```r
library(purrr)

map2_int(grep("^on", colnames(df)), 
         grep("^off", colnames(df)), 
         ~rowSums(df[, .x:.y]))

[1]  89 185 167  66
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did it like this because it requred "transpose" afterwards: `d=as.data.frame(t(data.frame(map2_dbl(grep("^on", colnames(df)), 
         grep("^off", colnames(df)), 
         ~rowSums(df[, .x:.y]))
         )))`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you would consider elegant - here is a Tidyverse solution (roughly 16 times slower than @benson23's solution on my machine):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# transpose and convert to tibble
df2 <- df |> 
  t() |> 
  as_tibble(rownames = "label", .name_repair = "none") |> 
  rename(value = 2)

# add counter and summarize
df2 |> 
  mutate(
    start = str_detect(label, "^(on|off)"),
    count = cumsum(start),
    grp = (count - 1) %/% 2
  ) |> 
  summarize(sum(value), .by = grp)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>     grp `sum(value)`
#>   <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1     0           89
#> 2     1          185
#> 3     2          167
#> 4     3           66
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thank you! By "elegant" I mean wrapping everything into one function to automatize and generalize it, rather than "do one function for the first two columns, then another function for the next three because the number of columns change, and then bind the two results together, and then transpose..." makes it even more disastrous if I were to have more than 10 columns, or a frequently changing number of the cols that have to be added together.